# How can I make this SVG adapt to viewport size without scaling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, responsive-design

I finally dared to start on a small, first project I was thinking about for a while after taking a few courses on full-stack developement and a little bit of design.

This [small sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5XE1.jpg) represents how I would like my navigation to look.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how I would make the SVG Path that underlines the nav scale like I want it to (The little ECG thingy should move without being squished while the lines next to it get smaller, check the picture to see what I mean).

This is the SVG Code:

```
<svg width="1440px" height="63px" viewBox="0 0 1440 63" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 49.1 (51147) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(0.000000, -20.000000)" stroke="#000000">
        <path d="M0,75 L684.996099,75 C686.664718,71.6666667 688.332684,70 690,70 C691.667316,70 693.333982,71.6666667 695,75 L712.215347,75 L715,82.3654775 L720,20 L725,78.2084488 L726.833442,75 L745,75 C748.15577,68.3333333 751.489104,65 755,65 C758.510896,65 761.84423,68.3333333 765,75 L1440,75" id="Path-3"></path>
    </g>
</g>
```

Do you guys have any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: i would make it fixed width with a big value and make it overflowing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above you can keep your element with a fixed big width and center it within the container and make it overflowing:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  width: 1440px;
  height: 63px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <svg width="1440px" height="63px" viewBox="0 0 1440 63" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 49.1 (51147) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(0.000000, -20.000000)" stroke="#000000">
        <path d="M0,75 L684.996099,75 C686.664718,71.6666667 688.332684,70 690,70 C691.667316,70 693.333982,71.6666667 695,75 L712.215347,75 L715,82.3654775 L720,20 L725,78.2084488 L726.833442,75 L745,75 C748.15577,68.3333333 751.489104,65 755,65 C758.510896,65 761.84423,68.3333333 765,75 L1440,75" id="Path-3"></path>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Is there a way to make the lines extend infinitely to the sides? Or is the only way to fake it by giving it a really big width?

Comment: Also, could you explain why you need the second div nested inside the container div?

Comment: @D.Breidert if you try without the second div you will see that it will be stretched because of the flex box so i had to add another one ;) ... concerning the ideas, for sure there other way to do, but this is the one i came with and actually i don't see any other idea :)

Comment: @TemamiAfif Thanks a lot!